# jQuery autcomplete input field text changes to value on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have a jquery autocomplete like this:

```
$( "#search" ).catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 2,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.post('translations/gettrans',{term: request.term}, function(data){
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                return {
                    label: item.label,
                    value: item.value,
                    category: item.category
                }
            }));
        },'json');
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var value = ui.item.value;
        var label = ui.item.label;

        $(this).val(value);
        $(this).text(label);

        $('#term').submit();
    }
});
```

The problem is when I select something in my dropdown the text field changes to the value. I want to value to change but the looks of the input not ..

How can I do this?

Comment: `catcomplete`  Typo? and where is reference to textfield? `$(this)` in select function is reference to your Input field?

Comment: No, I work with categories, so the manual shows catcomplete: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Comment: If `$(this)` reffers to the input field it won't work `The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val() method. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method.` from jquery docs

Comment: Please show a sample response of your `$.post('translations/gettrans'` call, in JSON format.